# Xubuntu's Network Manager cannot detect wifi on Lenovo G450 laptop

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, network-manager, lenovo

I just recently installed Xubuntu 14.04 on dual boot in my Lenovo G450 laptop. For some reason, I can only connect to the internet on an ethernet cable since the Network Manager fails to detect any wifi signal, be it mine or the neighbors'. The service providers for my wifi and the neighbors are the same, so they should have WPA2-PSK. The laptop can connect to wifi just fine when I boot into Windows 7.

I've been searching for solutions on the Net, but most of them seem situational and I'm not sure which is applicable. I'm also completely new to Ubuntu and have only been practicing very basic commands on the terminal for the last few days, so I also don't want to mess around with solutions that may end up doing more harm than good due to misapplication.

Comment: is wifi working? Are you able to switch wifi on and off? Have you installed drivers? What's the output of running `lspci` in terminal?

Comment: I had the same unit a while back, and I had to install the [Broadcom Driver](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php).

Comment: As I said, the wifi is okay. I can access it just fine when I boot into Windows 7. The following are the results of the lspci:  `04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)`

Comment: Oh, forgot to put up that the driver is 14e4:4315

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I'd like to thank Mitch for suggesting the Broadcom Driver. I went and installed it, initially to no avail, BUT it did get me searching for broadcom driver related issues and found one of the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers). What I needed to do was put in `# blacklist bcm43xx` in the terminal, and now I have no problems.